# replace content of table row on click, and change back again when clicked again

Tags: jquery, image

I have a table with multiple rows, and each row has 5 columns.
In one of these columns, there's a clickable icon. When this icon is clicked, I want to replace all columns (`td`'s) within that row with a new column spanning all 5 columns.
This would allow the icon (which is an image) use the full table width.

I have this so far:

```
/*  CSS  (less)  */
    .img { img { width:100%; } }


/*  javascript  */
$(function(){
    $('.dynochart').click(function(){
        var img_src = $(this).attr('src');  //  save image url
        var tr = $(this).parents('tr');  //  this row
        var tr_tds = $(this).parents('tr').children('td');  //  all columns within this row
        tr_tds.remove();  //  remove all columns from this row
        tr.append('<td colspan="5" class="img"><img src="'+img_src+'" class="dynochart_full"></td>');  //  insert new column with image spanning all columns
    });
});


/*  HTML  */
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td class="img"><img src="..." class="dynochart"></td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When clicking on the icon (`.dynochart`), it removes all the columns, and inserts a new one with an image spanning the whole available table width:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="5" class="img"><img src="..." class="dynochart_full"></td>
</tr>
```

So far, so good. It works.
But now, I would like to chacge it back to its normal state when I click this full-size image. So I thought it could be done like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.dynochart_full').click(function(){
        console.log('was clicked');
        var img_src = $(this).attr('src');  //  save image url
        var tr = $(this).parents('tr');  //  this row
        var tr_tds = $(this).parents('tr').children('td');  //  all columns within this row
        tr_tds.remove();
        /**
         *  retrive the orginale data columns
         */
    });
});
```

But it turns out that this approach doesn't work. Nothing happens when I click on the `.dynochart_full`-image. `console.log` detects nothing...

Any other way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do?
Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jLetyz9z/1/

Comment: Could you post your code as a jsfiddle?

Comment: Why remove them if you will want them back? Hide them or detach them.

Comment: here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jLetyz9z/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fmrrs1ju/3/)**

Toggle the tds and add the large image if it doesn't exist. The page renders as if hidden tds don't exist, so colspan applies only to visible tds.

Also bind the same event to `.bigimage` (but as they are created dynamically we must delegate).

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.dynochart, .bigimage', function(){
        // this isn't used // var tr = $(this).parents('tr');  //  this row
        var tr_tds = $(this).parents('tr').children('td');  //  all columns within this row
        tr_tds.toggle();  //  toggle visibility of all columns from this row

        // if this is the image (dynochart) do extra stuff
        if (this.tagName == 'IMG'){
            var img_src = $(this).attr('src');  //  save image url
            // add the image if it doesn't exist
            if (!tr.find('.bigimage').length){
                tr.append('<td colspan="5" class="img bigimage"><img src="'+img_src+'" class="dynochart_full"></td>');  //  insert new column with image spanning all columns
            }
        }
    });
});
```

On subsequent clicks, `td.bigimage` will toggle opposite to the original tds.

Or you could use CSS and simply toggle a classname on click.

Comment: Well. This worked exactly how I imagined.. Thanks for taking the time.